# cake php insert query working as update

Tags: cakephp

I have a insert query but it is working like update

controller

```
public function home() 
{
$this->loadModel("Ratings");
$aaddRatings = $this->Ratings->addRatings($this->data['id'],$this->data['searches'],$this->data['name'],$this->data['email'],$this->data['review'],$this->data['rating']);
$this->set(compact('aaddRatings'));
}
```

Model

```
public function addRatings($id,$searches,$name,$email,$review,$rating)
{
$this->create();
$aaddRatings =$this->save(array('id'=>$id,'searches'=>$searches,'name'=>$name,'email' => $email,'review' => $review,'rating' => $rating));
return($aaddRatings);
}
```

Debug

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `milgyonu_mber`.`ratings` AS `Ratings` WHERE `Ratings`.`id` = '19'      1   1   1
2   SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `milgyonu_mber`.`ratings` AS `Ratings` WHERE `Ratings`.`id` = '19'      1   1   1
3   SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM `milgyonu_mber`.`ratings` AS `Ratings` WHERE `Ratings`.`id` = '19'      1   1   1
4   UPDATE `milgyonu_mber`.`ratings` SET `action` = 'NO', `id` = '19', `searches` = 'Advanced Neurology & Super Speciality Hospital', `name` = 'shyam', `email` = 'test@gmail.com', `review` = 'test msg', `rating` = '2' WHERE `milgyonu_mber`.`ratings`.`id` = '19'
```

Comment: could you print the 'save' script, to be able to analyze the 'insert' query? Because if you check your Debug console line 4, there is an update, not insert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because you have the id field set, if there is a primary key in the save array CakePHP treats it as an update of that record.

Remove that and it should be fine!

Update::

```
public function addRatings($id,$searches,$name,$email,$review,$rating) {
    $this->create();
    $aaddRatings =$this->save(array('id'=>$id,'searches'=>$searches,'name'=>$name,'email' => $email,'review' => $review,'rating' => $rating));
    return($aaddRatings);
}
```

should be:

```
public function addRatings($id,$searches,$name,$email,$review,$rating) {
    $this->create();
    $aaddRatings =$this->save(array('searches'=>$searches,'name'=>$name,'email' => $email,'review' => $review,'rating' => $rating));
    return($aaddRatings);
}
```

if you have something else set as the primary key for this model then you probably havent specified it in the model

Comment: @but i dint set id field as primary key

Comment: but id need to set some manual value in id field so what should i do?

Comment: Why do you? what is your primary key on that table?

Comment: there are no primary key in this field but this table is work same like comments

Comment: ok thanks now i added another field as primary key and now its working thanks alot :) Voycey